# Is the ending of Echoes Of The Eye affected by progress in the base game?

Tags: outer-wilds, outer-wilds-echoes-of-the-eye

At the end of the DLC for Outer Wilds...

> ...you meet The Prisoner and they give the player a vision of the "crime" they committed to be imprisoned. They then hand over their device and the player gives a vision to them: a summary of events since the population of the Stranger entered the simulation of their home moon. It covers the deterioration of the ring world inside the Stranger, a basic history of the Nomai activity in the solar system, and the efforts of the Hearthians to explore and investigate. This information seems relatively free of spoilers for the base game, even though that information would be worth communicating.

Having played the DLC on a fresh save, I'm wondering whether a more complete ship's log would alter or extend the sequence in question?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, your ship log progress affects what appears in this cutscene. With a completed log, the cutscene will show the following:

> the Nomai seeing the signal from the Eye, then the Nomai Vessel warping into the Dark Bramble, then the Vessel releasing 3 escape pods, and then the Nomai being killed by ghost matter from the Interloper.